# Can't get a django model instance with the instance's own id

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model:

```
class ActivationCode(models.Model):
    id = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', to_field='id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I was having a hard time selecting an ActivationCode instance, so I tried to get the instance using its own id:

```
activation_codes = ActivationCode.objects.all()
print len(tuple(activation_codes))
>>> 1
for code in activation_codes:
    cid = code.id
ActivationCode.objects.get(id=cid)
>>> DoesNotExist: ActivationCode matching query does not exist.
```

What's going on? Why does it say the object doesn't exist when I'm using its own id? How come I can get the instance using .all() but not .get()?

It might be worth noting that the above code is running in a class-based view in a test environment (TestCase). When I try the same thing in the terminal, it works fine.

Comment: Floats as primary keys are a Bad Idea.

Comment: What's the difference between having a float pk and an int pk?

Comment: You cannot guarantee the float representation is exactly the same on all levels. Python float implementation is interpreter-specific and likely differs in precision from your DB doubles.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I switched to an int pk and it worked fine. You should've made that your answer so I could've accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floats as primary keys are a Bad Idea.

You cannot guarantee the float representation is exactly the same on all levels. Python float implementation is interpreter-specific and likely differs in precision from your DB doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Django will [auto populate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) the primary key (id)

```
class ActivationCode(models.Model):
    #OMIT THIS id = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', to_field='id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can call

```
code = ActivationCode.objects.get(pk=cid)
```

If you want the number of items in the db (more efficient than len)

```
count = ActivationCode.objects.count()
```

As a side note, calling `exists()` on a queryset

```
if qs.exists():
    ....
```

Is more efficient than

```
if qs:
    ...
```

Comment: Like the link says, "If Django sees you've explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won't add the automatic id column." My requirements call for a custom id, so I set it myself. Even when I don't need a custom id, I usually set it anyways. Explicit is better than implicit, right?